# Migrating issue with Python Social Auth on Heroku (Django app)

Tags: python, django, heroku, migration, python-social-auth

I've set up everything for [social auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) on my app, and it does work on localhost. Now I'm trying to deploy it to Heroku, but when I try to login with Facebook (for example) I get this error:

```
relation "social_auth_usersocialauth" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._admin", "custom_user_customuser"."is_staff" FROM "social_au...
```

I've tried *python manage.py makemigrations* and then *heroku run python manage.py migrate*, but it's not working; when I fire "migrate" I get this:

```
Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Comment: you will need to do ./manage.py makemigrations socialauth

Comment: I get "App 'socialauth' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?"

Comment: Well there's your issue. If you are using social auth it should be in it!

Comment: social auth is in it, but it's called "social.apps.django_app.default" in INSTALLED_APPS. Anyway, I think I've solved this, but now I'm on to something new.

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations social

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the app name change for python-social-auth --> social-auth-app-django and the associated app label changes.

You need to upgrade to social-auth-app-django>=1.0.0 to resolve this problem:

`Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.`